# R - Importing ASCII data using a .sas dictionary file and SAScii

Tags: r, ascii

I recently download some data in ASCII format that came with SAS setup files which I would like to use with R.  One such data file is here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8474088/Data.txt

with corresponding SAS setup file here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8474088/Setup.sas

I should note that the setup file is designed to work with around 50 different data files all with similar structure (the link above is an example of one of these).

I thought I was in good shape after finding the SAScii package but have been unable to get read.SAScii or parse.SAScii to work with these files.  Either command gives an error.

```
read.SAScii(data.file,setup.file,beginline=581)

Error in if (as.numeric(x[j, "start"]) > as.numeric(x[j - 1, "end"]) +  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 

parse.SAScii(setup.file,beginline=581)

Error in if (as.numeric(x[j, "start"]) > as.numeric(x[j - 1, "end"]) +  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

The examples given in the SAScii documentation use much simpler setup files so I am wondering if the complexity of the above file is causing the issue (for example the information on VALUE listed in the file prior to the INPUT command).

Any thoughts on how to proceed would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for noticing.  I just changed the links which should be working now.

Comment: Just made a quick attempt here - getting the same results regardless of playing with a few options/edits. You might have to bite the bullet and use `?read.fwf` manually to suck in the data. This is essentially what `read.SAScii` does internally anyway. SAS file formats are notorious for having bizarre exceptions to standard structure, so don't feel bad.

Comment: I appreciate you taking a look.  I also created some edited setup files to try to get it working but I think the long pre-ample before the INPUT stuff is required.  To be honest I can always use SAS to do it at the computer labs at school (hopefully, as I have never used SAS). However, I am also a big fan of the elegant R solution that can circumvent the whole licensed software deal.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

as noted in the [details section of the parse.SAScii help](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sascii/docs/parse.SAScii), this package cannot read overlapping columns.. and your file clearly has 'em.  ;)  in order for SAScii to work, you'll have to break the `.sas` file into four separate `.sas` files on your hard drive.  here's how-

```
# load all necessary libraries
library(stringr)
library(SAScii)
library(downloader)

# create two temporary files
tf <- tempfile()
tf2 <- tempfile()

# download the sas import script
download( "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8474088/Setup.sas" , tf )

# download the actual data file
download( "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8474088/Data.txt" , tf2 )

# read the sas importation instructions into R
z <- readLines( tf )

# here are the break points
z[ substr( str_trim( z ) , 1 , 1 ) == '#' ]

sas.script.breakpoints <- which( substr( str_trim( z ) , 1 , 1 ) == '#' )

script.one <- z[ 581:sas.script.breakpoints[1] ]
script.two <- z[ sas.script.breakpoints[1]:sas.script.breakpoints[2] ]
script.three <- z[ sas.script.breakpoints[2]:sas.script.breakpoints[3] ]
script.four <- z[ sas.script.breakpoints[3]:length(z) ]

# replace some stuff so these look like recognizable sas scripts
script.one[ length( script.one ) ] <- ";"

script.two[ 1 ] <- "input blank 1-300"
script.two[ length( script.two ) ] <- ";"

script.three[ 1 ] <- "input blank 1-300"
script.three[ length( script.three ) ] <- ";"

script.four[ 1 ] <- "input blank 1-300"

# test then import data set one
writeLines( script.one , tf )
parse.SAScii( tf )
x1 <- read.SAScii( tf2 , tf )

# test then import data set two
writeLines( script.two , tf )
parse.SAScii( tf )
x2 <- read.SAScii( tf2 , tf )

# test then import data set one
writeLines( script.three , tf )
parse.SAScii( tf )
x3 <- read.SAScii( tf2 , tf )

# test then import data set four
writeLines( script.four , tf )
parse.SAScii( tf )
x4 <- read.SAScii( tf2 , tf )
```

Comment: I ended up using SAS at school to get the data (looping through individual files and exporting to .csv).  However, the data source I use is standard in supplying data files in .txt format with with .sas files for setups so I might try this in the future.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: there's nothing to try.  the code above does all the work for you ;)

Comment: I finally ended up having a reason to use this (on a something a bit different) and it worked great.  Thanks.